# Monitoring JBOSS EAP 6.1 with JMX

Tags: plugins, jboss, jmx, nagios, jconsole

im trying to monitoring a jboss server with [Nagios Plugin](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Java-Applications-and-Servers/check_jmx/details) . This plugin is working to me with another versions of Jboss, but no with this.

I think that the problem is in the JMX connection and im trying to configure JMX to connect remotly by jconsole. My jboss version is Jboss-eap-6.1 and java version "1.7.0_79". I configured the next option:

```
-Djboss.bind.address.management=YOURSERVERIP
```

If i connect via http with my firefox, i can acces to the console by port 8080 with success.

Im reading that the jmx port is configured by default, but im not able to connect by Jconsole. I have try to connect by 2 ways:

- service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://$hostname:9999/jmxrmi
- service:jmx:remoting-jmx://:9999

I receive the same error with both ways.

Meanwhile, i read that i have to configure some parameters in the standalone.conf. I put some parameters like below:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<PORT>"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<IP_ADDRESS>"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/jboss/logmanager/log4j/main/jboss-logmanager-log4j-1.0.0.GA.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/apache/log4j/main/log4j-1.2.16.jar"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.logmanager"
```

With these configurations i received an error of logmanager. Im searching how to fix this error but all tests that i tried have been unsuccesfull..

The aim of all this is check a Jboss server with a nagios plugin. I try to use this plugin with other jboss versions and works right.. Im desesperate... Any ideas?

Im getting this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gJ0x.jpg

Comment: Whats the error message you are getting?

Comment: I resolve the problem. Libs were missing in the project to connect with remotting-jmx.